# Installing Tomcat6 on RHEL 6.4

Tags: redhat, tomcat

I am missing some packages which Tomcat depends on. 
But whatever dependency I try to resolve, it all comes down to java-gcj-compat missing which I cannot find on the DVD.

Note that I don't have an internet connection on the server so yum is not an option. Downloading something and putting it on the server isn't one either I'm afraid.

So basically, my question goes: Is it possible to install Tomcat6 with packages on the RHEL6.4 DVD? And if yes, how do I do it?

Cheers

Comment: what is the system arch ? 32 or 64 bit ? can you provide output of cmd `uname -p`?

Comment: It's a 64-Bit system. uname -p gives
x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Check that your RHEL DVD is known to yum as noted [here](http://weichong78.blogspot.co.at/2010/04/yum-install-from-mediarepo-in-fedora.html):

```
# mount /dev/cdrom /mnt -t iso9660 -o ro
# cp /mnt/media.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
# echo -e "baseurl=file:///mnt/\nenabled=1\n" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/media.repo
```

Yum tells you which package dependencies resolve to:

```
# yum deplist tomcat6
Loaded plugins: product-id, security
Finding dependencies: 
[...]
  dependency: java-gcj-compat
   provider: java-1.5.0-gcj.x86_64 1.5.0.0-29.1.el6
[...]
```

As you can see in the output above, the dependency `java-gcj-compat` is provided by `java-1.5.0-gcj`.

You might consider creating your own RPM for tomcat with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm), host your own yum repository and download it from there during installation.

I'm not sure whether this is frowned upon, but we rolled our own because we run it with Oracle's JDK and don't care about gcj.

Comment: I'm not much of a linux pro. Do you know which package contains java-gcj-compat? I googled but I don't see something like java-x.xx-gcj-compat...rpm in the Packages folder.

Comment: @l1mb0 I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks but here's what's odd. When I try to install `java-1.5.0-gcj-15.0.0-29.1.el6.x86_64` (in my case), he comes up with `sinjdoc` is missing. Trying to install that, gives me: `java-gcj-compat` is missing. Hen and egg problem?

Comment: @l1mb0 Verify that you are using the correct yum repositories and that your system is registered with RHN. Come find me in chat if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks @fuero but like I said. The server is completely offline. Do you think there is a way to install Tomcat with just the packages on the RHEL CD? I find it hard to believe that this shouldn't be possible. It comes with it so it should be installable.

Comment: @l1mb0 missed that, sorry. check my answer again, this should help.

Comment: OK - now I added the DVD as a repository to YUM and it works like a charm. Thanks for steering my thinking in the right direction ;-)

If anyone reads this who is as much of a n00b as I am, add to your /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-source.repo the following:

`[rhel-dvd]
name=RHEL DVD
baseurl=file:///media/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0`

Keeping the format, you can put what you want in the first two lines. For the baseurl make sure it corresponds to your mountpoint. Set all other `enabled` in the file to 0.

Then save and type `yum install tomcat6`

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to install Tomcat is from a [tar.gz](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)

One would only need Java pre-installed.